# image data representation

Tags: image, png

I wanted to know if I would be able to decompress a png with png++ and be able to get an access to the pixels with a file pointer and store them in a 2d or a 3d array and represent them in a hex format as the final result like a hex editor would. If not could anybody please suggest me a way I can do the same .

Intended language : c++
platform : linux.

Thanks in advance .

Answer (score 0):

use fread to get the values but you should know how the header is stored how many bytes of header length of data part start and end; i recommend start looking into this wiki page and try to read values using fread http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Network_Graphics

Comment: That is exactly what i did for bitmaps which were fairly easy. But will the same hold good for compressed image formats ? jpegs and tiffs ? or would i have to use a decompression technique using an image library and then use fread?

Comment: for c++ there is very good Library called CxImage; which is opensource , but i am not sure about linux compatibility i have used it on windows platform

Comment: for CxImage use look at this link http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1300/CxImage